# XML and XSD provided, need an XSLT for HTML output

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I've been given XML which represents a document. The provider uses this to hand to XML-FO and generate a PDF.

I need to generate HTML output which matches (to the best of our ability) the PDF.  The provider has no XSLT.

Are there any tools that can take an XSD and XML and generate a base XSLT, or where should I start with this? Are there any boilerplate XSLTs?

Answer (score 1):

I use `fo2html.xsl` from RenderX for this.  Check out my conference paper where I describe its use in a project to publish US Intelligence Documents from XML where fidelity between the HTML and the PDF was critically important:  http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/links/ipepaper.htm

I've used this stylesheet in a number of projects where the client needs an HTML rendering similar to the PDF rendering.  The wonderful thing is that almost everything is done for you ... if you need HTML specific stuff that is beyond what the module does, you can encode that by embedding your own annotations in the XSL-FO.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and it's a into for me so it's appreciated. What I feel like I'm missing (and I have not read your whole paper yet so let me know if it is in there) Can you point me in the right direction for generating the XML-FO output from the XML document? Are there libraries for this or? I looked at Apache's FOP, but it looks like it needs XML-FO to begin with?  I'm wondering if there is something I can hand the XSD and XML to and generate the XML-FO.

Comment: In your original question I understood you to have the XSL-FO from the provider that is creating the PDF.  Since an XSL-FO file is an XML file, it can be input to an XSLT transformation.  For the project I cited (and for a dozen other clients), I pass the XSL-FO document to the fo2html.xsl stylesheet (adapted as described in my paper), and I get an HTML document that looks pretty much like the PDF document created from the very same XSL-FO file.  For the client, fidelity is more important than stylishness, and by not writing a separate XSLT for XML to HTML I can, hand on heart, promise that.